# Add Security Group to EC2 instance using AWS CDK Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy an EC2 with the following properties:

```
        EC2securitygroup = ec2.CfnSecurityGroup(
          self,
          "EC2SecurityGroup",
          group_description="Security group for EC2",
          group_name="EC2-security-group",
          vpc_id="vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          security_group_ingress=[............])
        instance = ec2.Instance(self, "EC2instance",
          instance_type=ec2.InstanceType("t2.micro"),
          machine_image=amzn_linux,
          vpc = vpc,
          role = role,
          security_group = EC2securitygroup
        )
```

but the output from "cdk synth" shows empty SecurityGroupIds.

```
EC2Instance770AAE32:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties:
    AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
    IamInstanceProfile:
      Ref: EC2InstanceInstanceProfile4A6C6689
    ImageId:
      Ref: SsmParameterValueawsserviceamiamazonlinuxlatestamzn2amihvmx8664gp2C96584B6F00A464EAD1953AFF4B05118Parameter
    InstanceType: t2.micro
    SecurityGroupIds: []
```

How come the security group in the code was not being used?
BTW, I verified the security group was created but not being used by the EC2.

Can someone point out where I did wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Swap the order in which you're creating the instance and the security group?

Comment: I copy/paste in the wrong order, the order in the code is correct with security group created before instance but the EC2 still not using the security group created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `security_group` prop of the `ec2.Instance` constructor expects an `ISecurityGroup` and you're passing a `CfnSecurityGroup`, so I'm not sure how this even synthed. Use the `ec2.SecurityGroup` construct instead.

Comment: Changed to ec2.SecurityGroup and resolved the issue.  Thank you!